# Rails: set a value upon submit based on nested models values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose in my rails application I have a model Entry, which has a nested model Measures, such that each entry has_many measures (and measures belongs_to entry).

Each measure has its own incentive. Is it possible that Entry has an integer also named incentive, whose value is equal to the sum of all of its measures? How do you achieve this?

To me, it seems like this kind of becomes a two part question:
How to make a models field, upon submission, be defined based on another fields value? Then.. How to make a value, upon submission, be defined based on its nested models values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implement a callback using `after_update` in the model of the nested attributes, which updates its parent:

```
class Measure < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :calculate_measure_sum

  ...
  private

  def calculate_measure_sum
    # calculate sum
    self.entry.save
  end
end
```

You might need to use the same method on the `after_create` callback as well.

**EDIT:**

After having read about `touch` in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604931/order-by-association-created-at-or-by-own-created-at-if-no-association), I'd like to update my approach:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :measures
  after_touch :calculate_measure_sum

  ...
  private

  def calculate_measure_sum
    # calculate sum
    self.entry.save
  end
end

class Measure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry, touch: true
  ...
end
```

What happens here, is that everytime a Measure is created or edited, it informs its Entry that it is updated by calling its [touch method](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch). In the entry, we may use the callback `after_touch` in order to recalculate the sum of the measures. Note that the `after_touch`-callback is called on creation, deletion and modification of the measures.

Compared to my previous approach, this approach puts the responsability on the Entry-objects, which is favourable from a design point-of-view.

Comment: I am upvoting you for answering my question. This looks right and makes sense to me although I have not implemented it yet before. I will try it out, and likely be marking this answer as correct in the near future.

Comment: I am interested in solutions where the parent acts more like an observer. That is, changes to nested objects automatically triggers callbacks in the parent. If anyone have a neat solution to this, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Yep, good answer man. This is the proper way to do it, I like your solution and it worked well for me. self.entry.save (undefined method entry) only has to be self.save.  Other than that, flawless. Well done thank you +1