# Order by association created_at, or by own created_at if no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, associations

My group model has_many posts, posts have_many comments.

When I show the posts on a group, I want to order by the created at of the most recent comment, if there are any on a post, or by the created_at of the post itself.

So an old post would jump back to the top of the list if it has a new comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stick to a little different approach: your `Comment belongs_to :post` and `belongs_to` accepts `:touch` option. Set it to `true` and your Post's `updated_at` will be automatically updated on a Comment's modification. This way you can freely show your posts ordered by their `updated_at`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add commented_at:datetime column into posts table, then add before_create callback to Post model:

```
before_create :set_default_commented_at

def set_default_commented_at
  self.commented_at ||= Time.now
end
```

And add :touch to belongs_to association of Comment model:

```
belongs_to :post, touch: :commented_at
```

After all you'll be able to order by commented_at column.